# Can't write back into the same CSV file that I got data from

Tags: python

So I have a matrix with 10 columns. Each column comes from rows from a csv file that I read. I need to input said data into the csv file again (and another data point that I already calculated). I can't use csv writer

```
def escribir():
    columna = ["Nombre","Carnet","Examen","Proyecto","Nota Final"]
    datos = [str(matriz[0]),"\n",str(matriz[1]),"\n",str(matriz[2]),"\n",str(matriz[3]),"    \n",str(matriz[4]),"\n",str(matriz[5]),"\n",str(matriz[6]),"\n",str(matriz[7]),"\n",str(matriz[8]),"    \n",str(matriz[9])]
    archivo = open("archivo.csv","w")
    archivo.writelines(columna)
    archivo.writelines(datos)
    archivo.close()


NombreCarnetExamenProyectoNota Final['Juan', 'B48670', '80', '92', '86.0']
['Maria', 'B98635', '85', '89', '87.0']
['Marcela', 'B65872', '100', '70', '85.0']
['Enrique', 'C08563', '87', '95', '91.0']
['Luis', 'B86763', '92', '85', '88.5']
['Osvaldo', 'C15860', '85', '80', '82.5']
['Heidi', 'C25863', '70', '75', '72.5']
['Fernando', 'C35964', '65', '80', '72.5']
['Gerardo', 'C45790', '60', '60', '60.0']
['Estefania', 'B95605', '96', '90', '93.0']
```

I don't really know how to separate each line into an individual Excel cell, also I don't know why I can't                write on the 2nd row when writing datos, and I don't like it to look like that when written on Excel.

```
Nombre, Carnet, Examen, Proyecto, Nota Final
Juan,B48670,80,92,
Maria,B98635,85,89,
Marcela,B65872,100,70,
Enrique,C08563,87,95,
Luis,B86763,92,85,
Osvaldo,C15860,85,80,
Heidi,C25863,70,75,
Fernando,C35964,65,80,
Gerardo,C45790,60,60,
Estefania,B95605,96,90,
```

Comment: Why are you using `writelines()` at all?  Calling `write()` with one plain string i.e. `archivo.write("Nombre,Carnet,Examen,Proyecto,Nota Final\n")` is better and simpler.

Comment: Also, it seems like the elements inside `matriz` are sub-lists themselves.

Comment: Python has built in support for reading and writing CSV files; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.  You should use a `csv.writer`.

Comment: @StephenC They said they can't use csv writer (but did not say why).

Comment: Ah ... OK.  Probably homework :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you open a CSV file with Python's built-in function, open(), it is treated as a text file.

To separate each row like a cell in Excel by reading a file, you must read each row and separate it with a comma () or separator used in that file.

```
with open("archivo.csv", "r") as archivo:
    for line in archivo:
        cells = line.split(",")
```

In the above code, line.split(,") separates each line with a comma. This is helpful when reading simple CSV files, but it is much easier to use Pandas libraries when reading complex formats.

I recommend using 'pandas' library.

If you will use pandas, you can do it as below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv")
```

And,I'll show you examples of a simple usage..

For example,

1. To extract the value of the first column in the first row (0,0),

write this.

`value = df.iloc[0, 0]`

(value type depends on the data type of the cell. For example, numeric data can be int or float.)

Or  `value = df['your_column_name'].iloc[0]`

2. To extract all data in Row or Column

`column_values = df['your_column_name']`

this return pandas' series with all the values in that column.

`row_values = df.iloc[0]`

this selects rows based on index numbers.

If you want to select multiple rows, you can pass a list of indexes:

`rows_values = df.iloc[[0, 1, 2]]`

+)

`matriz[0] = ['Juan', 'B48670', '80', '92', '86.0']`

This is it, right?

Then,

```
for row in datos:
    line = ','.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) + '\n'
    archivo.write(line)
```

Comment: I can't use pandas or any library this has to be with only write or writelines(). Rules of my college

Comment: Ok, first..

`matriz[0] = ['Juan', 'B48670', '80', '92', '86.0']`
This is it, right?

Then why don't you do it like below?

   `for row in datos:
        line = ','.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) + '\n'
        f.write(line)`

Comment: It seems be hard to read the code in the comments. I'll add it to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

> So I have a matrix with 10 columns

I think you mean 10 rows.

```py
matriz = [
    ['Juan', 'B48670', '80', '92', '86.0'],
    ['Maria', 'B98635', '85', '89', '87.0'],
    ['Marcela', 'B65872', '100', '70', '85.0'],
    ['Enrique', 'C08563', '87', '95', '91.0'],
    ['Luis', 'B86763', '92', '85', '88.5'],
    ['Osvaldo', 'C15860', '85', '80', '82.5'],
    ['Heidi', 'C25863', '70', '75', '72.5'],
    ['Fernando', 'C35964', '65', '80', '72.5'],
    ['Gerardo', 'C45790', '60', '60', '60.0'],
    ['Estefania', 'B95605', '96', '90', '93.0'],
    ]
columna = ['Nombre', 'Carnet', 'Examen', 'Proyecto', 'Nota Final']

with open('archivo.csv', 'w') as archivo:
    columna[-1] += '\n'
    columna = ','.join(columna)
    archivo.writelines(columna)
    for row in matriz:
        row[-1] += '\n'
        row = ','.join(row)
        archivo.writelines(row)
```

[image: archivo.csv]

Comment: I can't use csvwriter. This is homework from college and my professor wants us to only use write or writelines

Comment: updated reply without `csv` module, using `writelines`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it. I made a couple of changes bc we haven't used stuff like with open, but it works perfectly. Thank you!